# Print all rows of an array not equal to zero in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `out`. I want to print row numbers which have at least one non-zero element. However, I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

out = np.array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        , 423.81345923,   0.        , 407.01354328,
        419.14952534,   0.        , 212.13245959,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [402.93473651,   0.        , 216.08166277, 407.01354328,
          0.        , 414.17017965,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]])

for i in range(0,len(out)):
    if (out[i]==0):
        print(i)
    else:
        print("None")
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    if (out[i]==0):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The expected output is

```
[1,2]
```

Comment: `if any(out[i]):` or `if out[i].any():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `out[i]` is an array. When you check if this array is equal to zero, it returns an array of booleans. The `if` statement then returns an error. The following code should work:

```
solution = []
for idx, e in enumerate(out):
    if any(e): # if any element of the array is nonzero
        solution.append(idx)
print(solution)
```

The output is :

```
[1, 2]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How do I print the output like ```[1,2]``` using your code?

Comment: You need to store the values in a list. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

out = ... # 2d array here

rows = np.where(out.any(axis=1))[0].tolist()

# rows:
# [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

out = np.array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        , 423.81345923,   0.        , 407.01354328,
        419.14952534,   0.        , 212.13245959,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [402.93473651,   0.        , 216.08166277, 407.01354328,
          0.        , 414.17017965,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]])

for i in range(0,len(out)):
    if (abs(out[i]).sum()!=0):
        print(i)
    else:
        print("None")
```

This sums up all values of each index and prints you all rows that contain any non-zero values.

Comment: What if we have an array like [0, -1, 0, 1]? Better to use numpy's any :)

Comment: You also should avoid using `for i in range(0,len(out))` and indexing out after. It would be better to use `enumerate`.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs thanks for mentioning that! I added the abs() function to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

We have `where` and `unique` attributes in numpy which can help you to achieve this.

```
get_index = np.where(out != 0)[0]
rows = np.unique(get_index)
print(rows)
```